# Check if the series $n^2 x^n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Check if the series $n^2 x^n$ converges.

The first idea that springs to my mind is to apply the Cauchy root test: $$\sqrt[n]{n^2x^n} =x \sqrt[n]{n^2}=x(\sqrt[n]{n})^2$$ and so, as $n$ approaches infinity, the root approaches $x$. And so I can claim that the series converges is $0\le x <1$ and diverges if $x>1$. 
However, this method does not cater for a lot of cases, namely - negative $x$-values or $x=1$. Is there a way to fix this approach and analyze all possible values of $x$?

Comment: Check for absolute convergence?

Comment: For $x=1$ it apparently diverges, for $-1<x\le0$ it converges and for $x<-1$ it diverges. What type of proof are you looking for?

Comment: How do you know that it converges for $-1 < x < 0$?

Comment: @Aemilius. You showed that it converges for $0\le x<1$ (notice that all terms are positive), then if you just change signs of some terms, it must still converge.

Comment: @ThePirateBay, 
I think I need to show that this series converges absolutely before I can make this claim, don't I?

Comment: @Aemilius. You've already showed it for interval $0\le x<1$. Just ignore the remaining intervals, focus on some $x$ from that interval, the series converge absolutely, therefore it converges for $-x$ too.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply ratio test, then
$$\lim\left|\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}\right|=|x|$$
So clearly only for $-1<x<1$ series converges and for $x$ equals to $1$. We can easily verify it is divergent and for $-1$, by alternaring series test, we can easily say that it is divergent.

Another way of looking at this series is $n^{2}$ is clearly going to diverge but $x^{n}$ is geometric series which converges only when $-1<x<1$.

Comment: A lot of your answer is not displayed because you're not using MathJax. When you write `<x` then parser interprets it as HTML tag and because `x` is not a valid tag, it will be hidden. I edited your post, hope you'll learn from it.

Comment: Thanks...I will remember it next time...